# Maximo: can i filter the list on multiple criteria of Status field

Tags: maximo

when i list the inventory, the default setting filters the Status field with "!=OBSOLETE".
Can I put in a command that will not list any items with status of obsolete or pendobs.

or filter the list on 2 different status'

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list *to* two different statuses. For that you put something like (without the quotes) "=status1, =status2".
That same trick never worked for me to filter *out* more than one status. "!=status1, !=status2", for example, would not work.

Saved and default queries can help take care of that if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Where Clause, you could edit there query to state something like this:

```
status not in ('obsolete', 'pendobs')
```

This is the best way I've found to do an exclusive query as opposed to the standard inclusive query.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, you can add PENDOBS to the filter so you exclude OBSOLETE and PENDOBS. If you want the behavior of the application to change, you have to edit the Java .class file in this case. Some modules allow you to edit this from Application Designer, but it is strange that Inventory module, requires editing the .class file.

c:\IBM\SMP\maximo\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\WEB-INF\classes\psdi\webclient\beans\item\ItemAppBean.class

Below is the relevant Java code. You'd have to edit the Java file and rebuild your maximo.ear for the List view to exclude PENDOBS from the list view.

```
public void initializeApp()
    throws MXException, RemoteException
{
    DataBean resultsBean = app.getResultsBean();
    Translate translate = MXServer.getMXServer().getMaximoDD().getTranslator();
    String status = (new StringBuilder()).append("!=").append(translate.toExternalDefaultValue("ITEMSTATUS", "OBSOLETE", null, null)).toString();
    resultsBean.setQbe("status", status);
    resultsBean.reset();
    super.initializeApp();
}
```